# Get selected Item from embedded button click

Tags: jquery, html, button, drop-down-menu

I have this ul control:

```
 <ul id="AddedWifiList"></ul>
```

I add a li item using jquery:

```
 $("#AddedWifiList").append('<li><a href="#">' + connectionName +
      '</a> <input type="button" onClick="DeleteWifi();" class="btn btn-  danger btn-sm btn-sm" value="Delete"></li>');
```

The markup rendered fron the last attempt is:

```
<input type="button" onclick="DeleteWifi(Informed);" class="btn btn-  danger btn-sm btn-sm" value="Delete">
```

The error is:

```
Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Informed is not defined Script: https://192.168.0.4/Account/Settings Line: 1
```

My js function:

```
function DeleteWifi() {
    var connectionName = $('#AddedWifiList').val();
    alert(connectionName);
}
```

The alert value is blank.

i had tried doing this:

```
 $("#AddedWifiList").append('<li><a href="#">' + connectionName +
      '</a> <input type="button" onClick="DeleteWifi(' + connectionName + ');" class="btn btn-  danger btn-sm btn-sm" value="Delete"></li>');


function DeleteWifi(connectionName) {
    alert(connectionName);
}
```

errors with a parse error.

Comment: What is the parse error in the last example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `ul` elements do not have a `value` attribute to read. From the context of your code it looks like you're trying to get the `connectionName` value, which should be set on the button instead.

Also note that as you're appending the elements dynamically after the page loads you should use a delegated event handler instead of an inline one, as the latter are outdated and are no longer good practice to use. To read the value of the `connectionName` related to the button you can then use a `data` attribute.

With that said, try this:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var connectionName = 'connection_' + new Date().getTime();
  $("#AddedWifiList").append('<li><a href="#">' + connectionName + '</a><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-sm delete" data-connection-name="' + connectionName + '">Delete</button></li>');
});

$('#AddedWifiList').on('click', '.delete', function() {
  console.log('Removing ' + $(this).data('connection-name'));
  $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<button type="button">Add</button>
<ul id="AddedWifiList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code:- 
https://jsfiddle.net/obnoxiousnerd/ec9um5qz/10/

```
$("#AddedWifiList").append('<li><a href="#" id="Wifi">' + 'connectionName' +
      '</a> <button>Delete</button></li>');
$("button").click(function(){
      var connectionName = document.getElementById("Wifi").textContent;
    alert(connectionName);
});
```

Made some changes, but get it done.

Comment: You need to  select some element that has a value to read. Since your ul didn't had anything to read, I changed it to the a that was added and **Voila!** it worked

Comment: Yea but I'm kinda slow in typing so he pipped(what does this mean) me out

Comment: Thanks. you were just beaten in time by the other person. It does work